How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x} $ using integral?
I tried to find this limit
$$ \Omega = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x} $$
without using series or finding derivative of that function So I tried to use the integral
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} dt = \frac{1}{x} $$
then
$$ \Omega = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} (e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}) \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} dt $$
now the way that I think its wrong
$$ \Omega = \int_0^\infty \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} \left(e^{-(a+t)x}-e^{-(b+t)x}\right) dt $$
So
$$ \Omega = \int_0^\infty \left(-(a+t)+(b+t) \right) dt $$
which is diverge .
So how can I use the integral correctly ? and why its wrong ?
also can we get the limit for the second derivative by integral ?

$\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}=\int_a^b e^{-tx} dt$

The problem is that interchanging limits, derivatives and integrals is hard and cannot be done without some hypothesis being satisfied

@Jorge nice! I think the hypotheses are satisfied. The integrand is smooth and bounded by an integrable (on $[a,b]$) function. Interchanging integration and differentiation gives a limit of $\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}$ for $x\to 0$ which coincides with my numerical experiments.

Let $f(x) = \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}=\int_a^b e^{-tx} dt$. Then you are allowed to interchange limits and derivatives and integrals.
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b e^{-tx} dt = \lim_{x\to 0}  \int_a^b \frac{d}{dx} e^{-tx} dt = \int_a^b \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} e^{-tx} dt =
$$
$$
= \int_a^b \lim_{x\to 0} (-t) e^{-tx} dt = \int_a^b (-t) dt = \frac{a^2-b^2}{2}
$$
You could also notice that if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} f(x)=f'(0)$ by continuity of derivative, so
$$
L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int_a^b (e^{-tx}-1)dt}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \int_a^b\frac{ (e^{-tx}-1)dt}{x} = \int_a^b \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ (e^{-tx}-1)dt}{x} =
$$
$$
= \int_a^b \frac{d}{dx} e^{-tx}|_{x=0} dt = \int_a^b -t dt
$$
